# How can I get the original file bytes in Zapier JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, byte, zapier

I have a file as input and I can't get the bytes, when I zap for example with a file from Google Drive I get this as input:
[zap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGzyK.png)

[input result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjoH7.png)

> hydrate|||.eJx1jk9zgjAUxL_LOzMd_mmLMz0EoUwt1NGxY-XCxBA1gYQKAYuO373B2mP3uLu_fe8CpJKKSpWp_ovCBBAYwGSjsCQ0YzlMHM_1bHP8aABpG1WJtqH1LbAsZzQau54BmJCq1RN_rqNlwI7RMs8kFsNsTrtsx0qq14sTrvcNTC5wP3n3BVWHSi_Aoc9rrKq6edBvNIdQYFa-tJIoVknd27Yy14Dm6ZC8DghCSYGCD3u-XjgpD614PePJGan3YG-nU3OUiIUdr8I-4RsnORM75UU_R36EbvL3vdik8yXGi-P358YVvFBB75-CuIumZvm07ZZY2hTPrI76_JcJE4T-y8PoaL4tdekZrtfrD1kpc6s:1q14Ki:h48rK3jHmPQcT7ca4T0RPbELNVM|||hydrate

And of course, when I get the bytes it is not what I expect since they are not the same bytes of the original file I get the input via bundle.inputData.new_data, and this is my code:

```
const publishData = (z, bundle) => {
    ...
     const data = bundle.inputData.new_data;
     ...
     function publish(record, publisher, host) {...}

  
}
module.exports = {
...
     operation: {
         inputFields: [
             {key: "methods", label: "Method", choices: {hosted: 'Hosted', ipfs: 'IPFS'}, required: true},
             {key: "new_data", label: "Data", required: false}
         ],
         perform: publishData,
         sample: sample
     },
};
```

Do I need to dehydrate it to work whit the bytes?

I tried to read the bytes decoding the input, also i tried to just work with the input but it doesn't work. I expect to get the original file bytes to perform a hash function.

Thank you